# Append with existing java policy

Tags: java, policy, securitymanager, javapolicy

I have my custom policy file which I want to append to existing Java Policy programmatically but not from command prompt because there `=` for append and `==` to override.

If I try

```
System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
System.setProperty("java.security.policy","myPolicy.policy");
```

Then will it append with existing or override that ?

Answer (score 0):

In a general way, when you have a method prefixed with `set` it will not append anything but replace the curent value with the new one passed as an argument.
The method that will append something are generally prefixed with `add`.

So the value `myPolicy.policy` will override the existing one (if there is one) for the property `java.security.policy`.

Comment: Thanks for clearing the concept. So, if you could explain how to append in Java programmatically.